# How to connect my electron app using PouchDB (leveldb) with Cloudant or any other database that support couchDB and sync

Tags: node.js, electron, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm creating an electron app using pouchDB and I want the app to be able to diferents customers and sync the data between them. As an example I'm making the tutorial: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-getting-started-todo, I adapt the code to electron and I created a noSQL database at cloudant.

At the moment I can save data but I cannot sync with my remote db that is in cloudant. Here is the endpoint I'm using to sync data between both database.

[image]

Here is the error that I'm getting.
[image]

Here is the code of my script.js

```html
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

  var ENTER_KEY = 13;
  var newTodoDom = document.getElementById('new_todo');
  var syncDom = document.getElementById('sync-wrapper');
 

  // EDITING STARTS HERE (you dont need to edit anything above this line)
  var NodePouchDB = require('pouchdb');
  var db = new NodePouchDB('todos');

  var couchdb = require('felix-couchdb')
  var remoteCouch = couchdb.createClient(5984, 'https://ac725f4e-29ec-4614-8e96-02ebc74a529b-bluemix.cloudant.com/')


  db.info(function(err, info) {
    console.log("is working", info)
    db.changes({
      since: info.update_seq,
      live: true
    }).on('change', showTodos);
  });

  // We have to create a new todo document and enter it in the database
  function addTodo(text) {
    var todo = {
      _id: new Date().toISOString(),
      title: text,
      completed: false
    };
    db.put(todo).then(function (result) {
      console.log("everything is A-OK");
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('everything is terrible');
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  // Show the current list of todos by reading them from the database
  function showTodos() {
    db.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}).then(function(doc) {
      redrawTodosUI(doc.rows);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  function checkboxChanged(todo, event) {
    todo.completed = event.target.checked;
    console.log(todo);
    db.put(todo);
  }

  // User pressed the delete button for a todo, delete it
  function deleteButtonPressed(todo) {
    db.remove(todo);
  }

  // The input box when editing a todo has blurred, we should save
  // the new title or delete the todo if the title is empty
  function todoBlurred(todo, event) {
    var trimmedText = event.target.value.trim();
    if (!trimmedText) {
      db.remove(todo);
    } else {
      todo.title = trimmedText;
      db.put(todo);
    }
  }

  // Initialise a sync with the remote server
  function sync() {
    syncDom.setAttribute('data-sync-state', 'syncing');
    
    var opts = {live: true};
    db.sync(remoteCouch, opts, syncError);
  }

  // EDITING STARTS HERE (you dont need to edit anything below this line)

  // There was some form or error syncing
  function syncError() {
    syncDom.setAttribute('data-sync-state', 'error');
  }

  // User has double clicked a todo, display an input so they can edit the title
  function todoDblClicked(todo) {
    var div = document.getElementById('li_' + todo._id);
    var inputEditTodo = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
    div.className = 'editing';
    inputEditTodo.focus();
  }

  // If they press enter while editing an entry, blur it to trigger save
  // (or delete)
  function todoKeyPressed(todo, event) {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
      var inputEditTodo = document.getElementById('input_' + todo._id);
      inputEditTodo.blur();
    }
  }

  // Given an object representing a todo, this will create a list item
  // to display it.
  function createTodoListItem(todo) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.className = 'toggle';
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', checkboxChanged.bind(this, todo));

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.appendChild( document.createTextNode(todo.title));
    label.addEventListener('dblclick', todoDblClicked.bind(this, todo));

    var deleteLink = document.createElement('button');
    deleteLink.className = 'destroy';
    deleteLink.addEventListener( 'click', deleteButtonPressed.bind(this, todo));

    var divDisplay = document.createElement('div');
    divDisplay.className = 'view';
    divDisplay.appendChild(checkbox);
    divDisplay.appendChild(label);
    divDisplay.appendChild(deleteLink);

    var inputEditTodo = document.createElement('input');
    inputEditTodo.id = 'input_' + todo._id;
    inputEditTodo.className = 'edit';
    inputEditTodo.value = todo.title;
    inputEditTodo.addEventListener('keypress', todoKeyPressed.bind(this, todo));
    inputEditTodo.addEventListener('blur', todoBlurred.bind(this, todo));

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.id = 'li_' + todo._id;
    li.appendChild(divDisplay);
    li.appendChild(inputEditTodo);

    if (todo.completed) {
      li.className += 'complete';
      checkbox.checked = true;
    }

    return li;
  }

  function redrawTodosUI(todos) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('todo-list');
    ul.innerHTML = '';
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
      ul.appendChild(createTodoListItem(todo.doc));
    });
  }

  function newTodoKeyPressHandler( event ) {
    if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
      addTodo(newTodoDom.value);
      newTodoDom.value = '';
    }
  }

  function addEventListeners() {
    newTodoDom.addEventListener('keypress', newTodoKeyPressHandler, false);
  }

  addEventListeners();
  showTodos();

  if (remoteCouch) {
    sync();
  }

})();
```

Comment: [Don't paste images of errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Comment: why not? Flimzy

Comment: Because it's against policy for the reasons explained in the link I provided to you. Did you read it?

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get to where the problem sits, can you verify that you can speak to the Cloudant database normally, that is using `curl` from the command-line? Using `curl`, fetch a document by its _id, perhaps a document you created manually using the Cloudant dashboard. That should shake out any problems with authentication: I note you're using IAM, which isn't always straight-forward -- and to my knowledge, not supported by PouchDB (or wasn't, last time I looked).

If that is the problem, create a new Cloudant instance with IAM+Legacy credentials.